# UIButton leaves white background behind button image and title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I `UIButton`s with image and title on it. I am using `appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:` to change theme in the app. When I change the background and title colors of the UIButton depending on the theme I want, it leaves some white background behind the title and image of UIButton(Image below shows it).

How do I get rid of the white background behind the button label and image?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code for your each button.

```
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
btn.opaque = NO;
```

**In Detail**:

The root of your problem, the default background color of your buttons is white, therefore once you apply a background color/theme to your UIView where your buttons reside, then white color becomes visible and not looking good. Therefore I recommend to change btw color clearColor or UIView color to white.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. The UIView has the color you see as default color. Does the image and button label on a UIButton has some uiview beneath it?. If it has how to access it?

Comment: You are adding button on the top of UIView. Therefore, on the z plane, Button on the top, UIView is under. If you change button background color to clear, then there will be no background color for the btn

Comment: I am setting white color for uiviews globally like this:`[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[GoogleAdsViewController class]]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];`. I discovered that this is causing the problem. Not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Try the following `[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[GoogleAdsViewController class]]] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

Comment: Tried that already but that spoils my other views since I am using this for a theme.

Comment: you have set image in button background image or simple image?

Answer (score 0):

Either you might have set the image of button in background or your images themselves have white background.